# Error callback method being called after request to Node application

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I have a node application that runs as a web server, taking a POST request that contains a filename, a file path and contents of the file. It generates the file and returns a 201 message.

Here is the code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var writeFile = function(pathname, fileName, content)
{
    fs.writeFile(pathname + fileName, content, function(err) 
    {
        if(err) 
        {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
        return "";
    });
}


var handleRequest = function(request, response)
{
    try
    {
        if(request.url == "/save")
        {
            var fullBody = "";
            request.on('data', function(chunk) 
            {
                fullBody += chunk.toString();
            });


            request.on('end', function() 
            {
                value = JSON.parse(fullBody);
                var result = writeFile(value.savePath, value.fileName, value.fileText);
                response.writeHead(201, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
                response.end();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
            response.write('File Service Running');
            response.end();
        }
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
        response.end(error);
    }
}

http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(3000);
```

I then have a web page calling this service like so:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ savePath: path, fileName: fileName, fileText: xml });

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:" + port + "/save",
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response)
        {
            handler();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error)
        {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
```

I debug through the node service and it does everything without any problem. However the error callback gets called instead of the success callback

The error parameters are:

```
xhr: { readyState:4, responseText: "File Created", status: 201, statusText: "Created" }

status: "parsererror"

error: "Unexpected end of input"
```

Here is an example of a request from fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/save HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 64
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:44301
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:44301/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{"savePath":"C:\\test","fileName":"14735.xml","fileText":"test"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your example and I got it working by removing

```
dataType: "json"
```

The reason of this behaviour could be found in [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), as `dataType` represents

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

You could double check this by keeping it but adding

```
response.send('{ "test": 1 }');
```

before sending `response.end()` after writing the headers.

Comment: Thank you that was it :)